# Widget options are not updated

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I'm creating a plugin which creates a widget with some options. I've extended the `WP_Widget` class:

```
class Dynamic_Player_Widget extends WP_Widget {


    function Dynamic_Player_Widget() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'dyn-description', 'description' => 'Plugin description' );

        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'dynamic-player-widget' );

        $this->WP_Widget( 'dynamic_player_widget', __('Dynamic Playlist Audio Player Widget', 'description'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );

    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );

        wp_register_script( 'dynamicplayer-show', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/dynamic/js/dynamicplayer-show.js', array( 'jquery' ));
        wp_localize_script( 'dynamicplayer-show', 'dynamic_options', $instance );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'dynamicplayer-show' );
        ?>

        <div class='dynamic-image dynamic-maximize'></div>
        <ul id="dynamic-playlist" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            <li mp3="" ogg="" artist="" title=""></li>  
        </ul>

        <?php

    }

    //Update the widget 

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        //Strip tags from title and name to remove HTML 
        $instance['dynTotalWidth'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['dynTotalWidth'] );
        $instance['dynRepeatAllEnabled'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['dynRepeatAllEnabled'] );
        $instance['dynPlaylistVisible'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['dynPlaylistVisible'] );
        $instance['dynPlaylistHeight'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['dynPlaylistHeight'] );
        $instance['dynStoreInCookie'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['dynStoreInCookie'] );;   

        return $instance;
    }



    function form( $instance ) {

        //Set up some default widget settings.
        $defaults = array( 
            'dynTotalWidth' => 'Regular',
            'dynRepeatAllEnabled' => true,
            'dynPlaylistHeight' => '165',
            'dynPlaylistVisible' => false,
            'dynStoreInCookie' => true,
            'show_info' => true );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>


<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'dynTotalWidth' ); ?>">
        <?php _e('Totlal Width', 'example'); ?>
    </label>
    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('dynTotalWidth'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('dynTotalWidth'); ?>" class="widefat" style="width:100%;">
        <option <?php selected( $instance['dynTotalWidth'], 'Large'); ?> value="Large">Large</option>
        <option <?php selected( $instance['dynTotalWidth'], 'Regular'); ?> value="Regular">Regular</option>
        <option <?php selected( $instance['dynTotalWidth'], 'Small'); ?> value="Small">Small</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'dynRepeatAllEnabled' ); ?>">
        <?php _e('Repeat All', 'example'); ?>
    </label>
    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('dynRepeatAllEnabled'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('dynRepeatAllEnabled'); ?>" class="widefat" style="width:100%;">
        <option <?php selected( $instance['dynRepeatAllEnabled'], 'true'); ?> value="true">true</option>
        <option <?php selected( $instance['dynRepeatAllEnabled'], 'false'); ?> value="false">false</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'dynPlaylistVisible' ); ?>">
        <?php _e('Playlist Visible', 'example'); ?>
    </label>
    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('dynPlaylistVisible'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('dynPlaylistVisible'); ?>" class="widefat" style="width:100%;">
        <option <?php selected( $instance['dynPlaylistVisible'], 'true'); ?> value="true">true</option>
        <option <?php selected( $instance['dynPlaylistVisible'], 'false'); ?> value="false">false</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'dynPlaylistHeight' ); ?>">
        <?php _e('Playlist Height', 'example'); ?>
    </label>
    <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('dynPlaylistHeight'); ?>" type="number" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('dynPlaylistHeight'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['dynPlaylistHeight']; ?>" class="widefat" style="width:100%;"/>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'dynStoreInCookie' ); ?>">
        <?php _e('Store in Cookie', 'example'); ?>
    </label>
    <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('dynStoreInCookie'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('dynStoreInCookie'); ?>" class="widefat" style="width:100%;">
        <option <?php selected( $instance['dynStoreInCookie'], 'true'); ?> value="true">true</option>
        <option <?php selected( $instance['dynStoreInCookie'], 'false'); ?> value="false">false</option>
    </select>
</p>


<?php
    }
}
```

This new class is called with:

```
function dynamic_player_widget() {
    if( ! is_active_widget('Dynamic_Player_Widget') )
    register_widget( 'Dynamic_Player_Widget' );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'dynamic_player_widget' );
```

The widget is shown correctly, but when I change the options in the widget menu the options turn to default again.

Any idea of what I'm missing or doing wrong?